# Postgresql replica upgrade using rsync on Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, upgrade, replication, rsync

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but the result is way off, trying to follow the procedure from [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html#PGUPGRADE-STEP-REPLICAS)

I ran from cmd following commands:

```
cd G:\Postgresql_test
rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive 12pro \ 13pro postgres@ip_here::postgresupgrade
```

In catalog `Postgresql_test` there are catalogs 12pro and 13pro with `data` catalogs in them.
Structure on replica server is identical, and `postgresupgrade` is a `G:Postgresql_test` directory on the remote server.

First of all there are plenty of errors on the beggining

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: \
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/g
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/$RECYCLE.BIN"
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/PostgreSQL" -- why this show catalogs that are above? directly on G:
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/Postgresql_test"
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/Postgresql_test- Copy" -- same here
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/postgres_upgrade" -- and here
file has vanished: "/cygdrive/g/Postgresql_test/\/System Volume Information"
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
```

After few minutes, on replica only 12pro catalog looks synchronized while 13pro grew just few hundred MBs (should be few GBs)

**@Edit1**

When I removed backslash between 12pro and 13pro it went without an errors in the console, but with same result. old catalog synced, the new one not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the `\` was just the syntax for a one-line command to be [split over two lines](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-multi-line-shell-code#1-using-a-backslash)

> The backslash (`\`) is an escape character that instructs the shell not to interpret the next character. If the next character is a newline, the shell will read the statement as not having reached its end. This allows a statement to span multiple lines.
>
> This is a useful technique that divides lengthy commands into readable statements contained within the shell session’s window.

---

To avoid potential path translation issues between Cygwin and the remote server, you can use relative paths. Start by navigating to the `G:\Postgresql_test` directory on your local machine in the Command Prompt. Then, adjust the rsync command to use relative paths for the source directories.

```
rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive 12pro/ 13pro/ postgres@ip_here:G:/Postgresql_test
```

Note the lack of trailing '`/`' in `postgres@ip_here:G:/Postgresql_test`.
I use the actual path instead of the `rsync.conf` alias `postgresupgrade`, but you can try with that alias if it works.

Make sure the `G:\Postgresql_test` directory exists on the remote server.

> "After few minutes, on replica only 12pro catalog looks synchronized while 13pro grew just few hundred MBs (should be few GBs)"

Reading from the documentation you mention "[Upgrade streaming replication and log-shipping standby servers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html#PGUPGRADE-STEP-REPLICAS)", check first if that is actually the right result:

When `pg_upgrade` is run in link mode (which is faster and uses less disk space), it does not actually duplicate all the data from the old cluster. Instead, it creates hard links from the new cluster directory to the actual data files in the old cluster directory. That means that the new directory (`13pro` in your case) might not occupy much additional space on the disk, even though it appears to contain a full copy of the data.

When you use the rsync command with the `--hard-links` option as suggested in the PostgreSQL documentation, it should replicate this setup on the standby server. That is, it should create a `13pro` directory on the standby server that also contains hard links to the data files in the `12pro` directory. That is what the documentation means when it says: "it then finds matching files in the standby's old cluster and creates links for them in the standby's new cluster."

So, it is possible that what you are seeing is correct: the `13pro` directory on the standby server might be smaller because it is mostly composed of hard links to the data in `12pro`. If you are unsure, you could compare the contents of the `12pro` and `13pro` directories on both the primary and standby servers to see if they look similar.

---

As noted by [sh4rkyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5861505/sh4rkyy) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731657/postgresql-replica-upgrade-using-rsync-on-windows/76745154?noredirect=1#comment135316289_76745154)

> It turned out it was an issue with the permissions to catalogs...
>
> Now both catalog looks well synced, but then this happened:
>
> `LOG: invalid primary checkpoint record PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record`
>
> So I used `pg_resetwal`, it helped to turn on the service, but then this happens:
>
> `FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist DETAIL: The database subdirectory "base/13466" is missing. ERROR: could not open relation with OID 2610`
>
> Which is very strange because `13466 catalog` doesn't exist on the primary server that run without any problems after upgrade.

That should mean there are inconsistencies in your PostgreSQL instance on the replica server.

The first error message, `LOG: invalid primary checkpoint record PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record`, references an issue with the Write-Ahead Log (WAL) files, which are used by PostgreSQL for recovery. That can occur when there are issues during the data copying process, perhaps due to errors or interruptions.
See also "[PostgreSQL Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) Trade-offs: Bounded vs. Archived vs. Replication Slots](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-wal-write-ahead-logging-management-strategy-tradeoffs)" by [Thom Brown](https://www.enterprisedb.com/thom-brown).

The command [`pg_resetwal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html) (formerly `pg_resetxlog`), which you used, is a utility that clears or adjusts WAL files in case of an emergency. However, it is a last resort tool and its usage can lead to some data loss.

The second error message, `FATAL: database "postgres" does not exist DETAIL: The database subdirectory "base/13466" is missing. ERROR: could not open relation with OID 2610`, indicates that the `postgres` database cannot be found on your replica server. The detail part suggests that the subdirectory corresponding to the `postgres` database, i.e., `base/13466`, is missing.

Now, why it is referring to the folder `13466` which does not exist in the primary server: PostgreSQL uses a [unique OID (Object Identifier)](https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/oid) for each database and these OIDs are used as the names of the directories holding the database files. These OIDs can differ between the primary and the replica server.

Considering these issues, I would recommend to:

- verify that the rsync command completed successfully without any errors. Make sure all the necessary files were copied correctly.
- verify the permissions on the replica server. Ensure that the PostgreSQL service has necessary read/write permissions to access the data files.
- try and reinitialize the replica using the `pg_basebackup` utility. That utility will make sure all necessary files are correctly copied to the standby server.

---

The OP adds in the comments:

> In addition to permissions issues, I have to admit my other omission... The 13 catalog on replica wasn't empty before rsync, I haven't cleaned it up after `initdb`.
>
> Now I finally completed successfully `rsync` upgrade.
> However, a new problem came up. I have an additional tablespace that is located in "`d:\tablespace_d`", I rsynced this tablespace successfully, but `pg_tablespace_location` shows "`pg_tblspc/16400`" so when I want to query a table it throws an error "`could not open file pg_tblspc/16400/PG_13_202010141/16403/2461`". I can't find how to change the path of this `tblspc`.
>
> `mklink /D P:\Postgresql\13pro\data\pg_tblspc\16400 D:\tablespace_d`: That one seems to work, I can query the table from this tablespace with no error.
> But when I want to check `pg_tablespace_location(oid)` it throws an `ERROR: could not read symbolic link "pg_tblspc/16400": Invalid argument`
>
> `/J` instead of `/D` works, `pg_tablespace_location(oid)` shows correct `pg_tablespace_location` and table is accessible

Note: The function [`pg_tablespace_location(oid)`](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_tablespace_location.html) is used to get the directory location of a tablespace. But when you use a symbolic link (`mklink /D`), it seems that PostgreSQL has trouble reading it and throws an error.

As you have seen, using a Junction (`mklink /J`) instead of a symbolic link can help. A Junction in Windows is similar to a hard link in Unix/Linux and is often used for directories.

In your case, the command:

`mklink /J P:\Postgresql\13pro\data\pg_tblspc\16400 D:\tablespace_d`

creates a Junction `P:\Postgresql\13pro\data\pg_tblspc\16400` that points to `D:\tablespace_d`. When accessed, it acts as though you are accessing `D:\tablespace_d`, and it seems that PostgreSQL can correctly interpret this.

As a general advice, you should always aim for the PostgreSQL data directories (including tablespaces) to be as consistent as possible across your systems to avoid such issues. In a real-world scenario, it would be best to plan your data directories and tablespaces before setting up your database to avoid having to create symbolic links or junctions.

Comment: I turned out it was an issue with the permissions to catalogs... Now the both catalog looks well synced, but then this happened:

 LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
 PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record

So I used pg_resetwal, it helped to turn on the service but then this happens:

FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
DETAIL:  The database subdirectory "base/13466" is missing.
ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 2610

Which is very strange because 13466 catalog doesn't exists on the primary server that run without any problems after upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. In addition to permissions issues, I have to admit my other omission... The 13 catalog on replica wasn't empty before rsync, I haven't cleaned it up after initdb. Now I finally completed succesfull rsync upgrade. However new problem came up. I have additional tablespace that is located in "d:\tablespace_d", I rsynced this tablespace succesfully, but pg_tablespace_location shows "pg_tblspc/16400" so when I want to query a table it throws an error "could not open file pg_tblspc/16400/PG_13_202010141/16403/2461". I can't find how to change path of this tblspc

Comment: mklink /D P:\Postgresql\13pro\data\pg_tblspc\16400 D:\tablespace_d
That one seems to work, I can query the table from this tablespace with no error
But when I want to check pg_tablespace_location(oid) it throws an 
ERROR:  could not read symbolic link "pg_tblspc/16400": Invalid argument

Comment: /J instead of /D works,

pg_tablespace_location(oid) shows correct pg_tablespace_location and table is accesible

Comment: @sh4rkyy Well done, good catch. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.